# Query mongodb using Predicate and sub-document $type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, querydsl, spring-mongo

What I am looking for is how do you translate a query using java spring mongodb based on type of the sub-document into a Predicate.

A normal query would look something like:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("data").type(3)).with(pageRequest);
```

How do I translate this into a predicate query?
Something like:

```
QEmployee employee = new QEmployee("employee");
return employeeRepository.findAll(employee.data.type.is(3), pageRequest);
```

But I am not sure how to translate it. Any help would be appreciated!

Does the current version of spring-mongo support it?

A part of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <sd.jpa.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</sd.jpa.version>
    <sd.mongodb.version>1.2.3.RELEASE</sd.mongodb.version>
    <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet supported in Querydsl. Feel free to create a ticket for it on GitHub.